# Get typescript generic type as string value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the name type of a type given in a generic function.

This is for a nodeJS app.

I would like to do something like this:

```
static Get<T>(): string {
        return typeof T;
    }
```

But this exemple results as an error: "'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

I would like "string" as a result if I call:

```
let strType: string = Get<string>();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that function?

Comment: The answer you've accepted gives you just a `string` whereas my answer gives you the exact literal string type e.g. `number`, `object` etc

Comment: The answer I've accepted tells that: "Since generics are not available at run time ", that is te answer of my question. Your answer is useful to bypass my problem. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since generics are not available at run time there is no way to call `typeof` on that. However you can do it like this

```
function Get<T>(type: T): string {
        return typeof type;
    }

let strType: string = Get<number>(1);
strType: string = Get<string>("1");
```

Comment: or just simply `Get(1)`, `Get("1")` (type inference)

Comment: @Ric Sure, at that point you can also simply call `typeof 1`.

Comment: Yep absolutely, not sure what the use case of this actually is, but this is the answer

Comment: You've explained the misconception correctly and concisely, but you should probably replace `T` with a non generic type `string | number | boolean | null | undefined` in your solution. Otherwise, the function may perpetuate the misconception in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can adapt this type from the [TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types):

```
type TypeName<T> =
    T extends string ? "string" :
    T extends number ? "number" :
    T extends boolean ? "boolean" :
    T extends undefined ? "undefined" :
    "object";

class Foo {

    static Get<T>(value: T): TypeName<T> {
        return typeof value;
    }
}

Foo.Get(123) // "number"
Foo.Get("str") // "string"
```